# Efficient way to create click targets larger that the actual scene object

Tags: three.js, raycasting

What’s a good way to have click targets that are larger than the actual scene object?

So far we have been using a larger invisible (yet raycastable) object to do this but it comes at the cost of requiring two draw calls instead of one.

Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

> So far we have been using a larger invisible (yet raycastable) object to do this but it comes at the cost of requiring two draw calls instead of one.

There is no additional draw call if you set [Object3D.visible](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=object3d#api/en/core/Object3D) to `false`. However, you can still perform raycasting against invisible 3D objects. Use [Raycaster.layers](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=raycas#api/en/core/Raycaster.layers) to selectively ignore 3D objects when performing intersection tests.

So what you are doing is already fine. You might want to consider to raycast only against bounding volumes if the raycasting performance becomes a bottleneck in your app. The idea is to create an instance of [Box3](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=box3#api/en/math/Box3) (AABB) or [Sphere](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=sphere#api/en/math/Sphere) (bounding sphere) of your actual scene object and only use it for raycasting.